# How to use promise with angular 2 and loopback?

Tags: elasticsearch, angular, loopback

Here shows the project done in angular2 framework with loopback.
I want to use promise along with data retrieved using loopback.

data.component.ts

```
ngOnInit () {
this.dataService.getAllData()
.then(response => {this.data.push(response);});
}
```

data.service.ts

```
public getAllData(): any {
    this.my_model.find()
    .toPromise()
    .then((res : Response) => res);

}
```

I want to interpolate this data to the html view.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning a `Promise` in your `getAllData()`. You could try it like this:

data.service.ts

```js
public getAllData(): any {
    return this.my_model.find().toPromise();
}
```

data.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit () {
    this.dataService.getAllData()
    .then(response => { this.data.push(response); });
}
```

and somewhere in your template you can use this array:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <span>{{ item.id }}</span>
</div>
```